# Refresh data in depth trough multiple closed workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

**Situation**
I have 3 Workbooks in the format `.xlsx`, `Source`, `Manipulation` and `Result`. 
`Result` has a link to a cell in `Manipulation` wich again, has a link to a cell in `Source`.
As the data is manipulated inside `Manipulation`, I can not link `Result` to `Source` directly. 
This is a small example. The depth of the link varies between 3 and 7 layers.

**Problem**
When the data in `Source` is changed, `Result` does not notice this change if `Manipulation` is closed at that time.

**Question**
Is there a Setting or uncomplicated solution that allows Excel to refresh data in depth even through multiple closed Workbooks. 
The solution should **not** involve VBA or third party software, if possible.